# Retaining original file names when processing multiple raster files using R

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have the following problem: I need to process multiple raster files using the same function in R package `landscapemetrics`. Basically my raster files are parts of a country map, all of the same shape and size (i.e. quadrants. I figured out a code for 1 file, but I have to do the same with more than 600 rasters. So, doing it manually is very irrational. The steps in my code are the following:

```
# 1. I load "raster" and "landscapemetrics" packages: 
library(raster)
library(landscapemetrics)

# 2. I read in my quadrant: 
Quadrant <- raster("C:\\Users\\customer\\Documents\\ ... \\2434-44.tif")

# 3. I process the raster to get landscape metrics tibble: 
LS_metrics <- calculate_lsm(landscape = Quadrant)

# 4. Finally, I write it into a csv: 
write.csv(LS_metrics, file = "2434-44.csv")
```

I need to keep the same file name for my csv files as I had for tif (e.g. results from processing quadrant "2434-44.tif", need to be stored in "2434-44.csv", possibly in a folder in wd).

I am new to R. I tried to use `list.files()` and then apply a for loop, but my code did not work.
I need your advice.
Yours faithfully,
Denis

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really about iteration and character (filename) manipulation; not about landscapemetrics etc. There are many similar questions on this site and resources elsewhere that you can consult. The basic approach can be like this:

```
# get input filenames
inf <- list.files("/my/path", pattern="\\.tif$", full=TRUE)

# create output filenames
outf <- gsub(".tif", ".csv", basename(inf))

# perhaps put output files in particular folder
dir.create("out", FALSE, FALSE)
outf <- file.path("out", outf)

# iterate 
for (i in 1:length(inf)) {
   # read input 
   input <- raster(inf[i])

   # do something 
   output <- data.frame(id=1)

   # write output
   write.csv(output, outf[i]) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to help without further information. What was the issue with your approach of looping through all files using `list.files()`. In general, this should work.

Furthermore, most likely you don't want to calculate all available landscape metrics, but rather specify a subselection during the `calculate_lsm()` function call.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31124903)